# Confusion regarding #interrupt-cells configuration on PCA9555 expander

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, interrupt, device-tree

I'm trying to setup a device tree source file for the first time on my custom platform. On the board is a NXP PCA9555 gpio expander. I'm attempting to setup node for the device and am a bit confused.

Here is where I'm at with the node in the dts file:

```
ioexp0: gpio-exp@21 {
        compatible = "nxp,pca9555";
        reg = <21>;

        interrupt-parent = <&gpio>;
        interrupts = <8 0>;

        gpio-controller;
        #gpio-cells = <2>;

        /*I don't understand the following two lines*/
        interrupt-controller;
        #interrupt-cells = <2>;
};
```

I got to this point by using the [armada-388-gp.dts](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12-rc4/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/armada-388-gp.dts) source as a guide.

My confusion is on what code processes the `#interrupt-cells` property. The [bindings documentation](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12-rc4/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio-pca953x.txt) is not very helpful at all for this chip as it doesn't say anything regarding interrupt cell interpretation.

Looking at the `pca953x_irq_setup` function in the [source code](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12-rc4/source/drivers/gpio/gpio-pca953x.c#L623) for the pca9555 driver - I don't see anywhere that the `#interrupt-cells` property is handled. Is this handled in the linux interrupt handling code? I'm just confused as to how I'm suppose to know the meaning of the two interrupt cells.

`pca953x_irq_setup` for your convenience:

```
static int pca953x_irq_setup(struct pca953x_chip *chip,
                 int irq_base)
{
    struct i2c_client *client = chip->client;
    int ret, i;

    if (client->irq && irq_base != -1
            && (chip->driver_data & PCA_INT)) {
        ret = pca953x_read_regs(chip,
                    chip->regs->input, chip->irq_stat);
        if (ret)
            return ret;

        /*
         * There is no way to know which GPIO line generated the
         * interrupt.  We have to rely on the previous read for
         * this purpose.
         */
        for (i = 0; i < NBANK(chip); i++)
            chip->irq_stat[i] &= chip->reg_direction[i];
        mutex_init(&chip->irq_lock);

        ret = devm_request_threaded_irq(&client->dev,
                    client->irq,
                       NULL,
                       pca953x_irq_handler,
                       IRQF_TRIGGER_LOW | IRQF_ONESHOT |
                           IRQF_SHARED,
                       dev_name(&client->dev), chip);
        if (ret) {
            dev_err(&client->dev, "failed to request irq %d\n",
                client->irq);
            return ret;
        }

        ret =  gpiochip_irqchip_add_nested(&chip->gpio_chip,
                           &pca953x_irq_chip,
                           irq_base,
                           handle_simple_irq,
                           IRQ_TYPE_NONE);
        if (ret) {
            dev_err(&client->dev,
                "could not connect irqchip to gpiochip\n");
            return ret;
        }

        gpiochip_set_nested_irqchip(&chip->gpio_chip,
                        &pca953x_irq_chip,
                        client->irq);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my first time working with device tree so I'm hoping it's something obvious that I'm just missing.

Comment: I think you would have to take a look at the device tree binding of your `interrupt-parent` which looks to be a gpio node somewhere in your device tree.

Comment: This might help you : http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12-rc4/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/interrupt-controller/interrupts.txt

Comment: Your GPIO expander has an interrupt line to the host **and** support of being an interrupt controller. So, it means if you set your pin as interrupt source it will generate interrupt which is chained to the PIC on your platform. That's why those two lines appeared in DTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at all of the comments I did some additional reading and figured out my answer.

I now understand that I was misinterpreting some properties of the device tree. I was previously under the impression that the driver had to specify how all properties were handled. I now see that linux will actually handle many of the generic properties such as `gpios` or `interrupts` (which makes a lot of sense).

The documentation on the actual [interrupts binding](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12-rc4/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/interrupt-controller/interrupts.txt) was very helpful, not the documentation for the device driver.

Here is a bit more of a detailed explanation of how the translation from intspec to `IRQ_TYPE*` happens:

The function `of_irq_parse_one` copies the interrupt specifier integers to a `struct of_phandle_args` [here](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12-rc4/source/drivers/of/irq.c#L354). This arg is then passed to `irq_create_of_mapping` via a consumer function (e.g. `of_irq_get`). This function then maps these args to a `struct irq_fwspec` via `of_phandle_args_to_fwspec` and passes it's fwspec data to `irq_create_fwspec_mapping`. These functions are all found in [irqdomain.c](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12-rc4/source/kernel/irq/irqdomain.c#L590). At this point the irq will belong to an `irq_domain` or use the `irq_default_domain`. As far I can tell - the `pca853x` driver uses the default domain. This domain is often setup by platform specific code. I found mine by searching for `irq_domain_ops` [on cross reference](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12-rc4/ident/irq_domain_ops). A lot of these seem to do simple copying of `intspec[1] & IRQ_TYPE_SENSE_MASK` to the `type` variable in `irq_create_fwspec_mapping` via `irq_domain_translate`. From here the type is set to the irq's `irq_data` via `irqd_set_trigger_type`.

`of_irq_parse_one`:

```
/**
 * of_irq_parse_one - Resolve an interrupt for a device
 * @device: the device whose interrupt is to be resolved
 * @index: index of the interrupt to resolve
 * @out_irq: structure of_irq filled by this function
 *
 * This function resolves an interrupt for a node by walking the interrupt tree,
 * finding which interrupt controller node it is attached to, and returning the
 * interrupt specifier that can be used to retrieve a Linux IRQ number.
 */
int of_irq_parse_one(struct device_node *device, int index, struct of_phandle_args *out_irq)
{
    struct device_node *p;
    const __be32 *intspec, *tmp, *addr;
    u32 intsize, intlen;
    int i, res;

pr_debug("of_irq_parse_one: dev=%s, index=%d\n", of_node_full_name(device), index);

/* OldWorld mac stuff is "special", handle out of line */
if (of_irq_workarounds & OF_IMAP_OLDWORLD_MAC)
    return of_irq_parse_oldworld(device, index, out_irq);

/* Get the reg property (if any) */
addr = of_get_property(device, "reg", NULL);

/* Try the new-style interrupts-extended first */
res = of_parse_phandle_with_args(device, "interrupts-extended",
                "#interrupt-cells", index, out_irq);
if (!res)
    return of_irq_parse_raw(addr, out_irq);

/* Get the interrupts property */
intspec = of_get_property(device, "interrupts", &intlen);
if (intspec == NULL)
    return -EINVAL;

intlen /= sizeof(*intspec);

pr_debug(" intspec=%d intlen=%d\n", be32_to_cpup(intspec), intlen);

/* Look for the interrupt parent. */
p = of_irq_find_parent(device);
if (p == NULL)
    return -EINVAL;

/* Get size of interrupt specifier */
tmp = of_get_property(p, "#interrupt-cells", NULL);
if (tmp == NULL) {
    res = -EINVAL;
    goto out;
}
intsize = be32_to_cpu(*tmp);

pr_debug(" intsize=%d intlen=%d\n", intsize, intlen);

/* Check index */
if ((index + 1) * intsize > intlen) {
    res = -EINVAL;
    goto out;
}

/* Copy intspec into irq structure */
intspec += index * intsize;
out_irq->np = p;
out_irq->args_count = intsize;
for (i = 0; i < intsize; i++)
    out_irq->args[i] = be32_to_cpup(intspec++);

/* Check if there are any interrupt-map translations to process */
res = of_irq_parse_raw(addr, out_irq);
 out:
    of_node_put(p);
    return res;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(of_irq_parse_one)
```

`irq_create_fwspec_mapping`:

```
unsigned int irq_create_fwspec_mapping(struct irq_fwspec *fwspec)
{
    struct irq_domain *domain;
    struct irq_data *irq_data;
    irq_hw_number_t hwirq;
    unsigned int type = IRQ_TYPE_NONE;
    int virq;

    if (fwspec->fwnode) {
        domain = irq_find_matching_fwspec(fwspec, DOMAIN_BUS_WIRED);
        if (!domain)
            domain = irq_find_matching_fwspec(fwspec, DOMAIN_BUS_ANY);
    } else {
        domain = irq_default_domain;
    }

    if (!domain) {
        pr_warn("no irq domain found for %s !\n",
            of_node_full_name(to_of_node(fwspec->fwnode)));
        return 0;
    }

    if (irq_domain_translate(domain, fwspec, &hwirq, &type))
        return 0;

    /*
     * WARN if the irqchip returns a type with bits
     * outside the sense mask set and clear these bits.
     */
    if (WARN_ON(type & ~IRQ_TYPE_SENSE_MASK))
        type &= IRQ_TYPE_SENSE_MASK;

    /*
     * If we've already configured this interrupt,
     * don't do it again, or hell will break loose.
     */
    virq = irq_find_mapping(domain, hwirq);
    if (virq) {
        /*
         * If the trigger type is not specified or matches the
         * current trigger type then we are done so return the
         * interrupt number.
         */
        if (type == IRQ_TYPE_NONE || type == irq_get_trigger_type(virq))
            return virq;

        /*
         * If the trigger type has not been set yet, then set
         * it now and return the interrupt number.
         */
        if (irq_get_trigger_type(virq) == IRQ_TYPE_NONE) {
            irq_data = irq_get_irq_data(virq);
            if (!irq_data)
                return 0;

            irqd_set_trigger_type(irq_data, type);
            return virq;
        }

        pr_warn("type mismatch, failed to map hwirq-%lu for %s!\n",
            hwirq, of_node_full_name(to_of_node(fwspec->fwnode)));
        return 0;
    }

    if (irq_domain_is_hierarchy(domain)) {
        virq = irq_domain_alloc_irqs(domain, 1, NUMA_NO_NODE, fwspec);
        if (virq <= 0)
            return 0;
    } else {
        /* Create mapping */
        virq = irq_create_mapping(domain, hwirq);
        if (!virq)
            return virq;
    }

    irq_data = irq_get_irq_data(virq);
    if (!irq_data) {
        if (irq_domain_is_hierarchy(domain))
            irq_domain_free_irqs(virq, 1);
        else
            irq_dispose_mapping(virq);
        return 0;
    }

    /* Store trigger type */
    irqd_set_trigger_type(irq_data, type);

    return virq;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(irq_create_fwspec_mapping);
```